# Нужен Laravel validation rule который запрещает использования заданного поля в запросе

Tags: php, laravel

Нужен Laravel validation rule который запретил бы использование поля email .

*Посмотрел документацию* есть *rule* **accepted** но его назначение до конца не понял.

Помогите найти   **laravel *rule*** , который *запретит*  нахождение *заданных полей* в запросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `$input = $request->except('email');`. После чего отправлять оставшиеся поля на валидацию.

`accepted` нужен для валидации `checkbox`, в данном случае он не применим

Если Вам кровь из носу, как нужно сделать это через валидацию, а не игнорирование поля в запросе, то можете написать кастомное правило:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => [
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (isset($value) && $value !== null) {
                return $fail($attribute.' field is not allowed.');
            }
        }
    ]
]);
```

В случае с `FormRequest` нужно прописать данное правило в конструкторе класса

```
class SomeFormValidateRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function __construct(ValidationFactory $validationFactory)
    {

        $validationFactory->extend(
            'reject',
            function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
                return isset($value) && $value !== null;
            },
            ':attribute field is not allowed!'
        );

    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'reject',
        ];
    }
}
```